# My TableView crashes when I make the run App

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, parse-platform

I state that in my app I'm using Parse.com for storing and managing data.

In my tableview I have introduced two different custom cells. A is displayed if there is an image and the other hand is displayed if the image is not present.

Now everything seems to work but when I go to make the application run the Tableview crash reporting this error:

**2013-11-22 15:36:34.256 UniGo![17186:70b]** 
**Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:],/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:62**46**

Can you explain where I'm wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.FFTableView.delegate = self;
    self.FFTableView.dataSource = self;

    CellaSelezionata = -1;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self QueryForPost];
}

-(void)QueryForPost {

    PFQuery *QueryForFriend=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:FF_AMICIZIE_CLASS];
    [QueryForFriend whereKey:FF_AMICIZIE_A_USER equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [QueryForFriend whereKey:FF_AMICIZIE_STATO  equalTo:@"Confermato"];
    [QueryForFriend includeKey:FF_AMICIZIE_DA_USER];

    PFQuery *QueryYES = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:FF_POST_CLASS];
    [QueryYES whereKey:FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [QueryYES whereKey:FF_POST_SCELTI equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    PFQuery *normalPostByFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: FF_POST_CLASS];
    [normalPostByFriends whereKey: FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE  equalTo: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]];
    [normalPostByFriends whereKey: FF_POST_UTENTE matchesKey:FF_AMICIZIE_DA_USER inQuery:QueryForFriend];

    PFQuery *normalPostByUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:FF_POST_CLASS];
    [normalPostByUser whereKey:FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE  equalTo: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO]];
    [normalPostByUser whereKey:FF_POST_UTENTE equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[QueryYES,normalPostByFriends,normalPostByUser]];
    [query includeKey:FF_POST_UTENTE];
    [query orderByDescending:FF_CREATEDAT];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            ArrayforPost = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (PFObject *object in results) {
                [ArrayforPost addObject:object];
            }
            [self.FFTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];    

}


-(CGFloat)valoreAltezzaCella:(NSInteger)index {
    PFObject *objectPost = [ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *text = [objectPost objectForKey:@"Testo"];
    CGSize MAX = CGSizeMake(230, 10000);
    UIFont *FONT = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize altezzaLabel = [text boundingRectWithSize:MAX options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FONT }context:nil].size;
    return altezzaLabel.height;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [ArrayforPost count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFObject *ObjectPost = [ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // FIRST CUSTOM CELL
if (![ObjectPost objectForKey:FF_POST_IMMAGINE]) {

    static NSString *IdentificazioneCella = @"CellPost";

 FFCustomCellTimelineSocial * Cella = (FFCustomCellTimelineSocial *)[self.FFTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IdentificazioneCella];


    if (Cella == nil) {
        Cella = [[FFCustomCellTimelineSocial alloc]
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                    reuseIdentifier:IdentificazioneCella ];
    }

    Cella.backgroundCell.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    Cella.backgroundCell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(219/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:(1)].CGColor;
    Cella.backgroundCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    Cella.backgroundCell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    Cella.BackgroundText.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    Cella.BackgroundText.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(219/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:(1)].CGColor;
    Cella.BackgroundText.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
    Cella.BackgroundText.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    Cella.TimeBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    Cella.TimeBackground.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(219/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:(1)].CGColor;
    Cella.TimeBackground.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    Cella.ViewTestataCell.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    Cella.ViewTestataCell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(219/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:(1)].CGColor;
    Cella.ViewTestataCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    Cella.FFImmagineUtente.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    Cella.FFImmagineUtente.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
    Cella.FFImmagineUtente.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
    NSString *text = [ObjectPost objectForKey:FF_POST_TEXT];
    Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.text = text;
    [Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
    Cella.DataCorrente.text = dateString;

    NSString *NomeUser = [[ObjectPost objectForKey:FF_POST_UTENTE] objectForKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];
    Cella.FFNomeUtenteLabel.text = NomeUser;

    NSString *ImmagineUtente = [[ObjectPost objectForKey:FF_POST_UTENTE] objectForKey:FF_USER_FOTOPROFILO];
    Cella.FFImmagineUtente.file = (PFFile *)ImmagineUtente;
    [Cella.FFImmagineUtente loadInBackground];

    if (CellaSelezionata == indexPath.row) {
        CGFloat AltezzaLabel = [self valoreAltezzaCella: indexPath.row];
        Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame = CGRectMake(Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.origin.x, Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.origin.y, Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.size.width, AltezzaLabel);  }

    else {

        Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame = CGRectMake(Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.origin.x, Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.origin.y, Cella.FFTestoUtenteLabel.frame.size.width, 55);
    }

    PFObject *rowObject = [ArrayforPost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([[rowObject objectForKey:FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE ] boolValue]) {
        Cella.FlashPostImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FFNotificaFlash"];
    }

    else {
        Cella.FlashPostImg.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@" "]; }

    return Cella;
}


else {

        // SECOND CUSTOM CELL
    static NSString *IdentificazioneCellaIMG = @"CellIMG";

    FFCustomCellWithImage * CellaIMG = (FFCustomCellWithImage * )[self.FFTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IdentificazioneCellaIMG];

CellaIMG = (FFCustomCellWithImage * )[self.FFTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IdentificazioneCellaIMG];

    if (CellaIMG == nil) {
        CellaIMG = [[FFCustomCellWithImage alloc]
                  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                  reuseIdentifier:IdentificazioneCellaIMG ];
    }

    NSString *FotoPostSocial = [ObjectPost objectForKey:FF_POST_IMMAGINE];
    CellaIMG.FotoPost.file = (PFFile *)FotoPostSocial;
    [CellaIMG.FotoPost loadInBackground];

    CellaIMG.backgroundCell.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    CellaIMG.backgroundCell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(219/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:(1)].CGColor;
    CellaIMG.backgroundCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    CellaIMG.backgroundCell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
      CellaIMG.TimeBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    CellaIMG.TimeBackground.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(219/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:(1)].CGColor;
    CellaIMG.TimeBackground.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    CellaIMG.ViewTestataCell.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    CellaIMG.ViewTestataCell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(219/255.0) green:(219/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:(1)].CGColor;
    CellaIMG.ViewTestataCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    CellaIMG.FotoProfilo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    CellaIMG.FotoProfilo.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
    CellaIMG.FotoProfilo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    CellaIMG.TestoPost.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f];
    NSString *text = [ObjectPost objectForKey:FF_POST_TEXT];
    CellaIMG.TestoPost.text = text;
    [CellaIMG.TestoPost setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
    CellaIMG.DataPost.text = dateString;

    NSString *NomeUser = [[ObjectPost objectForKey:FF_POST_UTENTE] objectForKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];
    CellaIMG.NomeUtente.text = NomeUser;

    NSString *ImmagineUtente = [[ObjectPost objectForKey:FF_POST_UTENTE] objectForKey:FF_USER_FOTOPROFILO];
    CellaIMG.FotoProfilo.file = (PFFile *)ImmagineUtente;
    [CellaIMG.FotoProfilo loadInBackground];

    if (CellaSelezionata == indexPath.row) {
        CGFloat AltezzaLabel = [self valoreAltezzaCella: indexPath.row];
        CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame = CGRectMake(CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.origin.x, CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.origin.y, CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.size.width, AltezzaLabel);
    }
    else {

        CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame = CGRectMake(CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.origin.x, CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.origin.y, CellaIMG.TestoPost.frame.size.width, 75);
    }

    return CellaIMG;

    }
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    if (CellaSelezionata == indexPath.row)  {

        //SPAZIO INTERNO VERSO IL BASSO QUANDO APRI LA CELLA
        return [self valoreAltezzaCella:indexPath.row] + 60 * 2;
    }

    else {

        //GRANDEZZA CELLA PRIMA DI APRIRE
        return 155 + 10 * 2;
    }

}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {
    if ([self valoreAltezzaCella:indexPath.row] > 65) {
        return indexPath;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (CellaSelezionata == indexPath.row) {
        CellaSelezionata = -1;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;
    }

    if (CellaSelezionata >=  0) {
        NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:CellaSelezionata inSection:0];
        CellaSelezionata = indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];        
    }

    CellaSelezionata = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post full message it displays on crash ? Most probably you are returning a nil instead of cell for some case.

Comment: You left out the important part of the error message. Update your question (do not post in a comment) the rest of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier - can return you nil
```

You need to check that and create a cell if that happens:

```
FFCustomCellTimelineSocial * Cella = (FFCustomCellTimelineSocial *)[self.FFTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IdentificazioneCella];

if (Cella == nil) {
    Cella = [[[FFCustomCellTimelineSocial alloc] 
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I edited my code according to your advice .. Now It works! The app does not crash but the second cell is not displayed ... Does not display the contents of the second cell, you see only the white cell but without content ... Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What type of cell you expect it to be ?

Comment: I inserted the image of Tableview to make you understand better ... As you can see the first cell is displayed perfectly, however the second is wascompletely white ... The content of the second cell is identical to that of the first cell other than that has only addition to the contents of the first cell also has a UIImageView

Comment: Do you return correct amount of cell in delegate ? Try to debug if it's asking for this cell. Place some NSLog inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I put all the code pages containing the TableView ... The delegates were all connected and I do not think there are mistakes ... I do not understand where is my mistake

This is what 'that returns the second cell with NSLog

22/11/2013 16:13:45.273 Unigo! [17404:70 b] Cell: <FFCustomCellWithImage: 0xa9531c0; baseClass = UITableViewCell, frame = (0 0, 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0xa951f50>>

Comment: Can you try returning standard UITableViewCell instead your custom one and see if that works ? Hard to help with that. Try adding your code step by step. Return UITableViewCell first, later step by step add customization. My guess will be something from with frame / bounds operations.

Comment: I just solved ... I'm sorry it was my stupid mistake ... It 'amazing how a small mistake can make you lose every time two hours to find solutions stupid: (

  Lacked an "A" nell'identifier: (I wrote CellIMG instead of CellaIMG ... amazing!

Comment: Sometimes happens ;) Good that you find that.